# MTREE Export to Unreal Engine 5

Tags: unreal-engine, modular-tree-addon

I am using MTREE for creating trees for a game and I wanna export these tree to unreal engine 5. But I can only export the tree itself without the leaves because it is not part of the Mesh. How can I fix this or how can I add them to the Mesh, because there is also no layer for the leaves in my collection.

Comment: Did you try joining the tree and the leaves with Ctrl+J ?

Comment: Thats not possible because there is no layer for the leaves. It is just one layer/mesh (the original mesh (cube)) with the three and the leaves but the leaves are somehow not part of the mesh

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by *layers*. Please add to your original post screenshots and your blend file with https://blend-exchange.com/.